# How to print the array of json responses in laravel view?

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel-5.4

Ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.nonliveValues', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url :"{{url('getNonLiveValues')}}"  ,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType:"json",
      success: function (data)
      {
        //alert(data);
        $("#qcverifiedCount").html(data.verifiedCount);
        //alert(data.SKUID);
        $.each(data.verifiedValues,function(index,value){
             alert(value.SKUID);
        });
      },
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

This is my ajax request for the getting the values from db and need to display it on the view.

Controller:

```
public function getNonLiveValues()
{
  $verifiedValues= priceInfo::join('productDescription', 'productDescription.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
   ->join('productAdditionalInformation', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId', '=', 'productPriceDetails.productId')
   ->join('products_photos', 'products_photos.productId', '=', 'productAdditionalInformation.productId')->select('products_photos.filename','productPriceDetails.SKUID','productDescription.modelName','productPriceDetails.productName','productPriceDetails.stock','productPriceDetails.sellingPrice','productPriceDetails.nationalDelCharge')
        ->where('productPriceDetails.nonliveStatus', '=', "QCVerified")
      ->Where('productAdditionalInformation.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->Where('productDescription.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->Where('products_photos.nonliveStatus','=',"QCVerified")
      ->where('productPriceDetails.listingStatus','=',"Active")->whereNotNull('MRP')->whereNotNull('listingStatus')->whereNotNull('fulfillmentBy')->whereNotNull('ProcurementType')->whereNotNull('procurementSLA')->whereNotNull('stock')->whereNotNull('localDelCharge')->whereNotNull('zonalDelCharge')->whereNotNull('nationalDelCharge')->whereNotNull('packWeight')->whereNotNull('packLength')->whereNotNull('packHeight')->whereNotNull('packBreadth')->whereNotNull('HSN')->whereNotNull('GST')->whereNotNull('luxuryCess')->get();

     $verifiedCount=count($verifiedValues);
     return response()->json(array('verifiedValues'=>$verifiedValues,'verifiedCount'=>$verifiedCount));

  }
```

This is my laravel controller function where i am returning values from db and its count.

Here is a sample of the returned JSON:

```
[
  {
    "filename":"MEBFSrGg8rjB1Hao0LOb2php6XaNihWH9zZGYQTy.png",‌
     "SKUID":"SK8900",
     "mo‌​delName":"C123",
     "pro‌​ductName":"Video Door Phone",
     "stock":"6",
     "sellingPrice":"3",
     "nationalDelCharge":"3‌​"
  }
]
```

Comment: replace your alert with something which inserts the value into an appropriate place in the page. We don't know how you want to format it so it's up to you where you put it and what HTML you wrap it in. But from the line `$("#qcverifiedCount").html(data.verifiedCount);` just above, it seems you already know how to insert into your  page. So just do the same kind of thing instead of your alert. It's hard to see why this is causing you a problem?

Comment: before inserting into the appropriate place,I just checks it with alerting.But it shows undefined values

Comment: Don't know how to display it when I pass an array of json responses

Comment: Ok well if it's giving you undefined then clearly the JSON is not in the format you expected. Check your browser's developer tools, look in the network tab, find the ajax request to your URL, click on it, look in the response tab of that request, and look at the JSON structure. Then you can see how to iterate through it. If you aren't sure, post the JSON here (or a small sample, if it's very large) and we can help you.

Comment: `[{"filename":"MEBFSrGg8rjB1Hao0LOb2php6XaNihWH9zZGYQTy.png","SKUID":"SK8900","modelName":"C123","productName":"Video Door Phone","stock":"6","sellingPrice":"3","nationalDelCharge":"3"}]`

Comment: this is the json data I'm getting and the value for $verifiedCount is `1`

Comment: Well that data doesn't contain a verfiedCount parameter, does it. So I can't see, based on your controller code, how that can possibly be your real response. Is that just part of the response? Please can we see the full structure? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense. BTW your .each loop on its own, using that JSON, would be fine: https://jsfiddle.net/57yxbe4j/

Comment: `return response()->json(array('verifiedCount'=>$verifiedCount, 'verifiedValues'=>$verifiedValues));`

Comment: this is how I'm trying to return the responses from controller

Comment: And when trying echoing my $verifiedCount value it  simply echoes `1`

Comment: don't know how to print those two responses inside my view

Comment: yes you said all of that before, there is no reason to repeat yourself. I asked you to provide the rest of the JSON. As I explained, it's impossible for what you showed me to be the complete JSON, because there is no verifiedCount parameter. I need the full JSON structure, including the verifiedCount parameter, in order to understand the problem. I'm _guessing_ that you might need to write `$.each(data.verifiedValues,function(index,value){` but without seeing it it's hard to be sure.

Comment: just see my controller code for more references.

Comment: I think the verified count value is not returning as json data

Comment: it just displays the count value ie.,`1` by now

Comment: There's no reason to suspect verifiedCount is not JSON. It's returned within a command in the controller which wraps the output as JSON. And it appears to be part of `data`. `1` is a valid value for a JSON field. But again, that's not what I asked. If you would like my help please answer my questions. Did my suggestion above work?

Comment: ok..chillout..Got the solution

Comment: ok good. I am chilled out, no worries, but it's kinda frustrating when people ignore your questions and just write something else that's not really relevant, but yet they want your help.

Comment: yep,understood..Sorry from myself

Comment: `$("#vimage").html('<img  src="{{asset(Storage::url("public/uploadedImages/.'+value.filename+'"))}}" width="50" height="50" >');` with this code I'm not getting the image.Will you please help me with this

Comment: It shows error @ ` '+value.filename+'`

Comment: also your suggestions alone helps me in fixing this

Comment: Is this syntax `{{asset(Storage::url` a Laravel syntax? Is that something that Laravel evaluates? Because if it is, you can't just insert it on the client side like that, because Laravel/PHP has finished executing a long time ago, on the server. It cannot evaluate your statement now.

Comment: then how to display my images stored inside storage folder

Comment: ie.,storage/app/public/uploadedImages/`myImagename`

Comment: you can write the URL by hand, or you can inject the base of the URL into your JS as a string variable beforehand, using something like that syntax, and then append the filename onto it later when you get the ajax back. Or, you could have your ajax controller return the full URL instead of just the filename.